# How do I use a for loop to reuse a django form in a template

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

After struggling with this issue for a while, I am hoping someone here can point me in a more productive direction.

I am trying to take an indeterminate number of variables in a database (obtained through a different template) and render them on a webpage, each variable with a simple data entry form, to be saved back to the database. Basically, it's a tracker for analysis. Say I want to track my daily sleep, running time, and calorie intake (the variables). I have those saved in a database as variables and want to call upon those variables and show them on a webpage with a daily entry form. I am using a "for" loop right now and it renders the way I want it to, with the variable name and the form, but it is only saving the last item in the variable list. How do I amend the code below such that when I hit the save button for each form rendeded, it saves the information for that variable (not just the last one rendered).

Below is the code. Any and all help would be infinitely appreciated.

Models...

```py
class Variable(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # id the active user
    ENTRY_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('numeric', 'enter a daily number'),
        ('scale', 'rate daily on a scale of 1-10'),
        ('binary', "enter daily, 'yes' or 'no' "),
    ]
    variable = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    entry_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ENTRY_TYPE_CHOICES, default="numeric")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.variable

class DailyEntry(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    # date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # id the active user
    variable_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    variable_id = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0000)
    entry = models.FloatField(default=9999)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Daily Entries'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.variable
```

Form...

```py
class VariablesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Variable
        fields = ['variable', 'entry_type' ]
        labels = {'variable':'Dependent variable to track', 'entry_type': 'Type of measure'}

class DailyEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DailyEntry
        fields = ['variable_name', 'variable_id', 'entry', 'date']
        labels = {'entry': 'Daily entry', 'date': 'Date'}
        widgets = {'variable_name': forms.HiddenInput(), 'variable_id': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

Views...

```py
def daily_entry(request):
    ''' page to make daily entries '''

    vars = Variable.objects.filter(id__gt = 0 )

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted. GET submitted. Create a blank form
        form = DailyEntryForm()
    else:
        #POST data submitted. Process data
        form = DailyEntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.created_by = request.user
            data.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('entry_new'))

    context = {'form': form, 'vars': vars}
    return render(request, 'entry_new.html', context)
```

and HTML...

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}


  {% for var in vars %}
    <div>
      <ul>
        <h3>{{ var.variable }}</h3>
        <form class="" action="" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form|crispy }}
          <input type="hidden" name="variable_id" value="{{ var.id }}" >
          <input type="hidden" name="variable_name" value="{{ var.variable }}">
          <input type="submit" name="" value="Save" />
      </ul>
    </div>

  {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Any help, well, helps...

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you make relationship between `DailyEntry` and `Variable` in such a weird manner? Use a `ForeignKey`. Also you have uploaded the views again instead of the html.

Comment: Sorry. HTML posted...